Lambda@edge returns 200 but the page stylings not loading
I have below nodejs lambda configured at edge locations in viewer request event of the cloudfront distribution.
import { GetObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { randomBytes } from "crypto";

const region = "eu-west-2";
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region });
let contentType = 'text/html';

let staticHeaders = {
  "content-type": [
    {
      key: "Content-Type",
      value: contentType,
    },
  ],
};

export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  const uri = request.uri;
  const modifiedUri = uri.startsWith("/") ? uri.substring(1) : uri;
  const generalCsp = "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; connect-src 'self' data: https://api.mywebsite https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ https://api.gleif.org; font-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; img-src data: 'self'; manifest-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; form-action 'none'; frame-ancestors 'self';";
  const {csp, nonce} = generateCsp();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
  let contents = '';
  
  if (uri.endsWith('.js')) {

    contentType = 'application/javascript';
    try {
      contents = await fetchIndex(modifiedUri);
      console.log(contents);
      callback(null, {
        status: '200',
        body: contents,
        headers: {...staticHeaders, "content-security-policy": [{key: "Content-Security-Policy",value: generalCsp}]},
      });
    } catch (error) {
      callback(null, {
        status: '404',
        body: 'Not Found JS',
        headers: {...staticHeaders, "content-security-policy": [{key: "Content-Security-Policy",value: generalCsp}]},
      });
      return;
    }
    
  } else if (uri.endsWith('.css')) {
    
    contentType = 'text/css';
    try {
      contents = await fetchIndex(modifiedUri);
      console.log(contents);
      callback(null, {
        status: '200',
        body: contents,
        headers: {...staticHeaders, "content-security-policy": [{key: "Content-Security-Policy",value: generalCsp}]},
      });
    } catch (error) {
      callback(null, {
        status: '404',
        body: 'Not Found CSS',
        headers: {...staticHeaders, "content-security-policy": [{key: "Content-Security-Policy",value: generalCsp}]}
      });
      return;
    }
    
  } else if(uri == "/") {
    
    try {
      contents = await fetchIndex('index.html').replaceAll("<script ", `<script nonce="${nonce}" `);
      console.log(contents);
      callback(null, {
        status: '200',
        body: contents,
        headers: {...staticHeaders, "content-security-policy": [{key: "Content-Security-Policy",value: csp}]},
      });
    } catch (error) {
      callback(null, {
        status: '404',
        body: 'Not Found Index',
        headers: {...staticHeaders, "content-security-policy": [{key: "Content-Security-Policy",value: csp}]},
      });
      return;
    }
    
  } else {
    
    try {
      contents = await fetchIndex(modifiedUri);
      console.log(contents);
      callback(null, {
        status: '200',
        body: contents,
        headers: {"content-security-policy": [{key: "Content-Security-Policy",value: generalCsp}]},
      });
    } catch (error) {
      callback(null, {
        status: '404',
        body: 'Not Found Other',
        headers: {"content-security-policy": [{key: "Content-Security-Policy",value: generalCsp}]},
      });
      return;
    }
  }
  
};

const bucketName = "mywebsitebucket";

async function fetchIndex(key) {
  try{
    
    console.log(`Key is -------------${key}`);
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: key });
    const response = await s3Client.send(command);
    
    const streamToString = (stream) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const chunks = [];
        stream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
        stream.on('error', reject);
        stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf-8')));
      });

    const bodyContents = await streamToString(response.Body);
    return bodyContents;
    
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching file from S3:', err);
    throw err;
  }
}

function generateCsp() {
  const nonce = randomBytes(16).toString("base64");
  return {
    csp: "default-src 'self'; script-src 'nonce-"+nonce+"' 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; connect-src 'self' data: https://api.mywebsite https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ https://api.gleif.org; font-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; img-src data: 'self'; manifest-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; form-action 'none'; frame-ancestors 'self';",
    nonce,
  };
}


After configuring this, the url returns just a blank html page with response code 200. There are no errors anywhere. Could someone please suggest a workaround?
I've tried removing cache-control header, without attaching any security policy to the cloudfront both but none of those worked.

contents can be undefined in your code - can you confirm that it contains the actual HTML you expect?

@gshpychka  When I check, contents wasn't undefined but I could see all of my javascript,css etc. files are being overritten by the index.html page content. Therefore I've adjusted the lambda accordingly. But now, i'm getting 502 (Bad Gateway) error for my script and style files even though they are exist in the bucket
